# A basic question about the definition of $\Sigma_n$ completeness

Tags: logic, definition, recursion, computability

Suppose I want to show that $A$ is $\Sigma_8$-complete. By definition, this requires to prove, in particular, that $A$ is itself a $\Sigma_8$ set. But I don't really understand if I need to prove as well that $\Sigma_8$ is the "best" one could get? (I.e., that $A$ is not $\Sigma_i$ or $\Pi_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$.) Some $\Sigma_8$ sets may be as well $\Sigma_1$, but they still qualify for being $\Sigma_8$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different notions here:

- Being $\Sigma_8$.
- Being **properly** $\Sigma_8$, which is to say being $\Sigma_8$ but *not* $\Sigma_n$ for any $n<8$ (or $\Pi_k$ either for that matter for any $k\le 8$).
- Being $\Sigma_8$-**complete**.

If we want to show that something is $\Sigma_8$-complete, it is - as you say - not enough to simply show that it is $\Sigma_8$. But it is **also** not enough to show that it is properly $\Sigma_8$! $\Sigma_8$-completeness is a very strong property: we have to show that *any* other $\Sigma_8$ set is many-one reducible to the given set, and that doesn't follow from proper-$\Sigma_8$-ness alone. In order to prove that a set $A$ is $\Sigma_8$ complete, we have to prove two things:

- $A$ is $\Sigma_8$.
- Every $\Sigma_8$ set $B$ can be many-one reduced to $A$.

That's it - we never need to refer to proper-$\Sigma_8$-ness, and we don't get any benefit from doing so either.

*(That said, as a matter of practice basically every naturally-occurring properly-$\Sigma_n$ set is $\Sigma_n$-complete. So you can always take a proof of proper-$\Sigma_n$-ness as **really good evidence** for $\Sigma_n$-completeness. But this isn't a theorem or anything, it's just a fact about the sorts of sets we run into in mathematical practice ... at least, so far.)*

---

Note, incidentally, that it is **not** immediately obvious that $\Sigma_8$-completeness implies properly-$\Sigma_8$-ness! To get that you need to use the fact that the arithmetical hierarchy doesn't collapse, which takes a proof. Of course that's not hard, but it is worth noting - and it's worth keeping in mind that there *are* hierarchies out there which [*do*](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47333/examples-of-collapsing-hierarchies), or [*may as far as we know*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168912/what-is-so-wrong-with-polynomial-hierarchy-collapsing), collapse.

Comment: Now it's clear. I wonder why textbooks (e.g. Soare's textbook) don't distinguish between  being $\Sigma_n$ and being properly $\Sigma_n$. How is the reader supposed to know that the definition of $\Sigma_n$ completeness talks about being properly $\Sigma_n$?.. As for the second requirement in the definition of  $\Sigma_n$ completeness, I intentionally didn't mention it  (that's why I used "in particular" in my question) since my question is about the first requirement.

Comment: @user634426 "How is the reader supposed to know that the definition of $\Sigma_n$ completeness talks about being properly $\Sigma_n$?" Huh? It doesn't talk about it at all. $\Sigma_n$-completeness is defined purely in terms of $\Sigma_n$-ness, there's no need to mention proper-$\Sigma_n$-ness at all. I don't see what's missing in e.g. Soare, here.

Comment: @user634426 I've edited to, I hope, clarify this point.

Comment: Ohh, I thought to show that $A$ is $\Sigma_n$ complete, one has to show that it's properly $\Sigma_n$ and every $\Sigma_n$ set can be $m$-reduced to it. But now I see that one doesn't need to show proper $\Sigma_n$-ness.

Comment: Does a proof of proper-$\Sigma_n$-ness also a "really good evidence" for $\Sigma_n$-completeness if $n$ is other than $8$?

Comment: @user634426 Yes, that's for all $n$. I've fixed to clarify that.

Comment: I posted a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033833/proper-sigma-ness-of-sigma-n-complete-sets) to avoid posting too many comments here.